# How to remove $1$ at position $x$ ( in base $B$) from a number represented in Base $10$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, number-systems

I was going through a solution on code chef in which we needed to remove a $1$ from a position say $x$ (in Base $B$) from a number in Base $10$ if the representation of that number in base $B$ had a digit $\geq 1$.

One way is to change the base to $B$ and check and simply do it!

This guy subtracts $B^{x}$ (where Base is $B$ in which 1 was to be removed and x is the position of $1$ (starting from $0$)) from the decimal representation if and only if after subtracting it from the number , the number is $\ge 0$ .

Now, I know $B^{x}$ represents the $1$ at position $x$ in base $10$.

But I cannot think of  the logic behind it . Can you help?

Comment: What is $B^{\text{position}}$ ?  Generally, could you reformulate the problem using mathematical names for each of your variable.  I'm confused when you say "a number" or "a digit" without more specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number $n$ in base $b$ is written
\begin{equation}
a_0 + a_1 b + a_2 b^2 + \dots a_N b^N
\end{equation}
for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_i \in \{0, \dots, b-1\}$.

So when you subtract $1$ to the $x$th digit, you actually do :
\begin{equation}
a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 b^2 + \dots + (a_x - 1) b^x + \dots + a_N b^N.
\end{equation}

That way you can easily see that
\begin{equation}
(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 b^2 + \dots a_N b^N) - b^x =
a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 b^2 + \dots + (a_x - 1) b^x + \dots + a_N b^N.
\end{equation}

For what to do when $a_x=0$ or $n - b^x < 0$, this depends very much on what you try to achieve, and why you're doing this computation for.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the number you wrote only when $a_x$ is greater than or equal to 1 . how to check that condition was my question majorly

Comment: Take you number modulo $b^{x+1}$, and if that new number, $n' \in [0,b^{x+1}-1]$, is greater than $b^x$ (i.e. $n' - b^x \ge 0$), you have $a_x \ge 0$.  Is that what you want to understand ?

Comment: Yes, But taking modulo was the point i wanted.!!

Comment: But I really fear because he didnt did it anything and yet was able to solve!!